# Regarding different areas of specialisation in development economics in relation to their application for the betterment of real world

Tags: macroeconomics, development-economics

Developing economies need to put in lot of hard work in order to reach the level of developed economies of the world.Or to put it in other words,in order to improve the lives of the millions residing in these countries,where unemployment,increasing population and poverty is creating vicious circles,bringing them out of it is really a big challenge.

My question is: For a person who wishes to bring about a little change in the lives of those underprivileged people for their betterment,which area of specialisation in development economics would suffice?

Update: don't know where to put up this question here or somewhere else?

I searched stack exchange sites where I could put up this question.I did put up this question on academia SE,but they told me to post it on Economics SE.But here on this site none has answered my question.Can anyone help me out here?